# On the definition of Edwards curves group addition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I'm working with Hales [The Group Law of Edwards Curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05278.pdf) where he defines the addition $z_1 \oplus z_2 = (\frac{x_1x_2 - c y_1y_2}{1 - d x_1x_2y_1y_2}, \frac{x_1y_2+y_1x_2}{1+dx_1x_2y_1y_2})$ and he writes this is an element of $R_2[\frac 1 \delta] \times R_2[\frac 1 \delta]$ where $R_2[\frac 1 \delta]$ is the localization of $R_2 = \mathbb{Z}[c,d][x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2]$ with respect to the multiplicative set $S = \{1,\delta,\delta^2,\ldots\}$ where $\delta = \delta^- \delta^+ = (1 - d x_1x_2y_1y_2) (1+dx_1x_2y_1y_2)$

My problem is the case $\delta = 0$. I think with this notation the operation is still defined as $z_1 \oplus z_2 = ((x_1x_2 - c y_1y_2)(1+dx_1x_2y_1y_2),(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)(1 - d x_1x_2y_1y_2))$. This would mean I have to distinguish in my proofs the case $\delta = 0$ and $\delta \neq 0$.

Am I correct? Or can I safely assume that $\delta \neq 0$ in the proof of the group law of Edwards curves?

Comment: Does it make any sense to localize at $\delta=0$?

Comment: @PeterMelech if $\delta = 0$, then $S = \{1\}$? and in that case I think it would

Comment: Not so sure, I think the set $S=\{1,\delta,\delta^2,...\}$ would be $\{1\}$ for $\delta=1$ and the symbol $\frac{1}{\delta}$ is really forbidden for $\delta=0$. I think the author didn't explicitly say $\delta\neq 0$, but  You can safely assume this.

Comment: On the other hand $R_2[\frac{1}{\delta}]$ would be the zero ring then does that make any sense in Your context?(cf. Lemma 10.9.4 [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00CM))